# cloud and eucalyptus authentication experiment

Tags: cloud, virtualization, eucalyptus

In general we can enter to eucalyptus with some credentials.but i want to have my own authentication policy of implementing.Here i would like to use key distribution center for providing the  keys for confidentiality  so that user can have security features.. can anybody help me? is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Eucalyptus (2) do not have such a capabilities. With Eucalyptus 3 a feature is introduced to allow integration with LDAP or AD. Is this enough for your purposes?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion...but now i think eucalyptus 3 is not released yet..i am a student and i have to complete this project by may of next year..i am learning on this eucalyptus..do you know at exact date they release this project..is it a open source software..if eucalyptus is not there can i do this project with any other tools like hadoop.or with the use of hybridfox and eucalyptus version 2 can i (as administrator) show atleast some authenication to users...(or)can i change the source code of eucalyptus 2 to provide authentication to users ..please suggest me..

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the eucalyptus development branch it is having the latest code. It is available here:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~eucalyptus-maintainers/eucalyptus/eucalyptus-devel/files

In order to set it up on your system Andy's blog post can be a good reference:

http://agrimmsreality.blogspot.in/2012/01/building-eucalyptus-3-devel.html
http://agrimmsreality.blogspot.in/2012/01/configuring-eucalyptus-3-devel.html

Hope this helps!